# Sum of primes below and equal to 'n' not correct? what's wrong?

Tags: java, sum, primes

**_This code is correct but failing larger input testcases

Sum of primes below not correct? what's wrong?

Sum of primes below not correct?

sum of squares of the first n primes

Summing the first N primes [closed]

Here is the code I'm fighting with, please help me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a[] = new int[10000000];
    int b[] = new int[1000000];
    int c[] = new int[1000000];
    Arrays.fill(a,1);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=2;i<10000;i++)
        if(a[i]==1)
            for(int j=i*i;j<10000000;j+=i)
                a[j]=0;
    b[0]=b[1]=0;
    int k=2;
    for(int i=2;i<10000000;i++)
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            b[k]=i+b[k-1];
            c[k]=i;
            k++;
        }
    int t = in.nextInt();
    while(t-->0)
    {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=2;;i++)
        {
            if(c[i]==n)
            {
                System.out.println(b[i]);
                break;
            }
            else if(c[i]>n)
            {
                System.out.println(b[i-1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Respect for using the slide operator. But don't run before you can walk.

Comment: what? I can't get u!!!

Comment: @HariKiranVusirikala, since its one of the hackerrank problems and people solve those mostly to have fun while programming I think its better that you try yourself first with easier problems to learn to control loops and variables before going to this problem. Only hint I can give you here is that try finding the time complexity of your solution and think if that can fit the timelimit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[10000];
        int b[] = new int[10000];
        int c[] = new int[10000];
        Arrays.fill(a,1);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=2;i<1000;i++)
            if(a[i]==1)
                for(int j=i*i;j<10000;j+=i)
                    a[j]=0;
        b[0]=0;
        int k=1;
        for(int i=2;i<10000;i++)
            if(a[i]==1)
            {
                b[k]=i+b[k-1];
                c[k]=i;
                k++;
            }
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t-->0)
        {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(b[n]);
        }
    }   
}
```

This is the correct code and U can do sum upto 'nearly 1200 (<1300)' prime number sum .
If we want to get beyond that we can increase it in the code ..

Comment: but I want to print the sum of primes below 1000.

Comment: But u said in the question that U want sum of first n prime numbers

Comment: sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
int t = in.nextInt();
while(t-->0)
```

I put

```
 System.out.println("** b[1000] = " + b[1000]) ;
```

and got 3682913!
Your sum of first 1000 prime numbers is correct.
So, check your printing loop!

Comment: Thanks @bobjan, I will see.